# How to solve this issue on Firebase admin panel?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I'm trying to integrate firebase on Android project.
Everything works well, but I could see the customized class members was sorted in alphabetically rather than defined order when I visit Firebase Admin.

Here is customized class on Android code:

---

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class trackingData 
{
    public String Time;

    public double S1 = 0.0;
    public double S2 = 0.0;
    public double S3 = 0.0;
    public double S4 = 0.0;

    public double copX;
    public double copY;
    public double copD;

    public double VelocityX;
    public double VelocityY;
    public double VelocityD;

    public int copScore;
    public int stabilityScore;

    public fbTrackingData() {
        Time = "20000";
        S1 = 2.35;
        S2 = 3.55;
        S3 = 0;
        S4 = 0;
        copX = 0;
        copY = 0;
        VelocityX = 10.3;
        VelocityY = 10.5;
        VelocityD = 20.3;
        copScore = 10;
        stabilityScore = 5;
    }
}
```

And Here is screenshot on Firebase console.

[image: Firebase admin screenshot]

I want to see all the class members as defined order like "Time", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "CopX", "CopY", "CopD", ... , "copScore", "stabilityScore".

How can I solve it on either of Android or Firebase console?

Comment: Why you want to store data in such a order? I don't think it will help you in any performance related issue or something else. It will just maintain structure of your database as per your choice. Is there any specific reason to do this? Please let me know

Comment: AndiM, Thank you for your comment.

Yes, I have some reason to see members in defined order on Firebase admin.
I have to monitor all the added informations on admin panel at this moment.
Because the members are showing in randomized order, so I want to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Firebase is a JSON database. The order of properties in a JSON object is in general not defined and not maintained. The console shows the in alphabetical order. There is no way to change that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order those children in the Firebase console. There is no way for achieving this. What can you do instead, is to display those children according to your needs. So for that I recommend you using `orderByChild()` method. There are also 2 more methods, `orderByKey()` and `orderByValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

actully you don't order firebase admin panel in your desired way its permanently order in alphabtic by firebase team.